# Have Rails 3.1 model belong_to and still act as standalone without parents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an application that will have a model that `belongs_to` another model most of the time, but in some other instances it will just need to be standalone and not have parents.

Just an example:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pieces_of_paper
end

class PieceOfPaper < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :books
end
```

But sometimes I will need to save a piece of paper without it belonging to a book

What would be the best/proper way to code for this?

I have looked around for an example of this and couldn't find anything and maybe that's just it, I could just be over thinking this and it's very simple.  I'll be thankful for any help anyone can provide, thanks.

Comment: `book_id` can be `nil`. Are you running into a particular error?

Comment: No, still coding for it, but just wanted to make sure I did it as clean as I could my first time through, and like I said, I may just be over thinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's very simple and I think you are "over thinking" it. 
You can either test it in "rails console" or "unit test/rspec" environment.

e.g.  rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe PieceOfPaper do
  it "should be saved without assigning the book it belongs to" do 
    expect {
      # should create without error.
      PieceOfPaper.create(:book_id => nil)    
    }.to change(PieceOfPaper, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have decided to take it a step further with my project and use rspec and cucumber. Testing is the right answer.